# Unity. Windows Api. Find Running Game Window

Tags: c#, windows, api, unity-game-engine

I am currently using Unity multi display function. When I run my Unity app, it creates two windows in the task bar. One for each display I have.
I am able to - when the program starts - get the active window by using GetActiveWindow(). I have managed to manipulate this a little bit, but the next thing I'm trying to do has me stuck.

I'm trying to cycle through the other unity app windows. The one for the secondary display in this case, and then set it as the active window. Using SetActiveWindow() I would imagine.
However, I'm not too familiar with the convoluted Windows logic. I know I probably need to use FindWindow(), but the actual use of that code has me bewildered.

My question is: How can I reliably find and store every open Unity game/app window that is running?
(Not the editor. Only the Apps launched)

Comment: [EnumThreadWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumthreadwindows).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each window created by unity will have the same (or similar) class name or window title, you can either use `EnumWindows` (interop) function to retrieve a list of created windows and then checking each of them for their class name (you'll have to know the class name ahead, do this by using `GetClassName` (interop) function once and then storing it for later comparison with `EnumWindows`.

The other possibility would be to listen for the window creation event, therefore getting notified when a new window gets created. Once again, compare the class name or window title with the newly created window to see if it is a window created by unity.

If neither class name nor window title work for comparison (because they might be inconsistent) you can also retrieve the process name (use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to retrieve PID) and see whether it matches unity.exe.